# Is the proceedings of WG 2015 published?

Tags: graph-theory, conferences

Within theoretical computer science, the "Workshop on Graph-Theoretic Concepts in Computer Science (WG)" is one of the main specialized venues for publication of papers dealing with graph theory. It's 41st edition, WG 2015, happened in June 2015.

For several reasons I need to provide the full reference of a paper which appeared at WG 2015. However I could not find the proceedings online. It should have been published in LNCS. My questions are the following.

1. Were the proceedings already published?
2. If not, when will the proceedings be published?
3. What can I do to get the full reference information of the paper if the proceedings are not yet out?
4. Is it normal for a conference to take so long to publish the proceedings?

Comment: Not yet listed at DBLP and the conference web site says only that the proceedings will be published by LNCS. So although I have no definitive information (which is why this is a comment not an answer) it looks very much like it simply hasn't been published yet. It does seem long to me too. Even Graph DrawIng (another LNCS conference whose proceedIngs are publIshed after rather than at the conference) usually only takes around 4 months from the conference date.

Answer (score 7):

I am an author of a paper that is to appear in the WG 2015 proceedings. As far as I know, they have not appeared yet, which is indeed quite strange.

Early February I emailed the chair (Ernst Mayr) to ask for the page numbers of my paper; they were not yet known at that time. The chair informed me that he encountered a big technical problem when producing the files for the proceedings, but that the problems were cleared up and that he was in almost done compiling. If you want up to date info, I suggest emailing Ernst Mayr.

PS: The LNCS volume number will be LNCS 9224.

Comment: It's finally published: http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-53174-7